How to Enable USB Ports on Lenovo Monitor When Connected via Mini DisplayPort Cable?
I'm trying to use the built-in USB ports on my Lenovo monitor while it's connected to my laptop using a Mini DisplayPort cable. The video connection works perfectly, but I can't get the USB ports on the monitor to work with my peripherals (keyboard, mouse, USB drives).
My Setup:
Monitor: Lenovo L32p-30 80.01cms (31.5) UHD USB Type C monitor | 66C9UAC1IN | Lenovo IN (Photo of ports) 
Laptop: Lenovo ThinkPad T460 
Laptop Connection: Mini DisplayPort to DisplayPort cable (https://amzn.in/d/j2aiwk0) 
Issue: The USB ports on the monitor are not recognized by the laptop.
What I've Tried:
I have connected my laptop to the monitor via the Mini DisplayPort cable for the display.
Plugged in peripherals (like a keyboard and mouse) into the monitor's USB ports, but they are not working. What additional steps or connections do I need to make to enable the USB ports on the monitor? Is it even possible to use USB ports on monitor if connected via DP Mini cable? Are there any particular settings I need to adjust on the laptop or monitor?
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Is it even possible to use USB ports on monitor if connected via DP Mini cable? No, it isn't. The DP connection is for video (and audio) only.

Is there a USB input on the monitor? I've always connected a USB A-B cable from the PC to the monitor (same as a printer, basically), separately from whatever display cable I'm using. This brings USB to the monitor's hub.

@user8356  - Thank you for the reply. The monitor only has four USB 3.0 ports of type A,   would a USB A-A cable work?

You mentioned that it has USB C port also? I wonder if that can be the input that enables the other USB A ports (that is unusual, but possible). I have not seen a case where a USB A to A is needed, but that's possible too I guess. All the monitors that I've used have a USB type-B input and several USB type-A outputs.


Is it even possible to use USB ports on monitor if connected via DP
Mini cable?

No, it isn't. The DisplayPort and the HDMI inputs are for video (and audio) only.

What additional steps or connections do I need to make to enable the USB ports on the monitor?

You need to connect using a USB-C to USB-C cable that is specifically designed to support video transmission, such as a USB-C cable with DisplayPort Alt Mode or Thunderbolt.

As suggested by @user8356 in this comment, I'm looking for an additional cable that can carry signals from USB ports.

Already explained in the last paragraph. Those are the only cables you can use. The @user8356
comment isn't applicable to modern monitors, only to old ones that had an embedded USB hub independent of everything else connected by an AB- USB cable AND whatever video connection. Yours has a modern USB-C connection that can support video from compatible sources (req. Thunderbolt or alt video mode) as well as all the other USB functions. In order to use the USB-A ports in the monitor you must have the USB-C connection (it may work with an A to C adapter though)...

Your laptop doesn't have the required USB-C port so you could use everything in the monitor with a single USB-C cable. So you always need an additional cable to enable the USB ports.
